# Proof of a trace inequality involved matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was stuck for a long time to prove the following trace inequality:

$tr\left[\left(I_{M}+\Lambda D^{H} UU^{H}D\right)^{-1}\right] \ge tr\left[\left(I_{M}+\Lambda\right)^{-1}\right]$,

where $H$ is Hermitian transpose, $D^{H}D = I_{M}$, $\Lambda \in \mathcal{R}^{M \times M}$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative real diagonal entries, $U \in \mathcal{C}^{M \times M}$ is also a diagonal matrix and $tr \left[UU^{H}\right] = M$.

Clearly, when $UU^{H} = I_{M}$, the equality holds.
I have tried to run some simulations when $UU^{H} \neq I_{M}$ and this inequality always holds.
However, I can not find some useful theorems from the Matrix Analysis theory to prove this conclusion.

Anyone providing the proof or relevant hints will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D^H=D = I_M$, and 
\begin{equation}
UU^H = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1.1 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.9
\end{pmatrix}, 
\quad 
\Lambda = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1.0 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.5
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
In this sense, we have
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{tr}\left[\left(I_{M}+\Lambda D^{H} U U^{H} D\right)^{-1} \right] = \operatorname{tr} \left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
2.1 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 1.45 
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} 
\right] \approx 1.1658.
\end{equation}
And 
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{tr}\left[\left(I_{M}+\Lambda\right)^{-1}\right] = \operatorname{tr}
\left[
\begin{pmatrix}
2.0 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 1.5 
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\right] 
\approx 1.1667.
\end{equation}
One can double check if it is indeed a counterexample or there is a mistake in my calculation.

Comment: Hi Ze-Nan, thank you for this good example! I deed run some simulations with $D$ as a DFT matrix but forgot the special case with $D = I_{M}$! Let me see my problems again, maybe I lose some constraints. BTW, any idea when $D$ is a DFT matrix? Thanks a lot!